# Denying user object access to a computer setting GPO

Tags: group-policy

Let's say I have a GPO called gpo1 which sets some computer settings.

I want these computer settings to apply only to certain user. Is it possible in the delegation tab to add a user group and then deny them the read / apply this gpo rights?

I'm not sure if it would work because the gpo1 is setting some computer settings and not user settings.

Thanks !

Comment: Computer settings apply to computers, user settings to users.

Comment: Yeah, this I know, but there is a specific GPO that I want activated for some user which is only in the computer settings.  

I want to prevent users printer redirection on a RDS server, and that GPO is not available trough the user settings, it is only available in the computer section. 

I would like for a given terminal server to apply this only for certain users

Comment: @JohDoh it isn't possible. You might need some kind of loopback processing, but as it stands this question isn't answerable.

Comment: Ok, I tried with loopback processing but this only applies to  users settings applied to a computer. 

It merges the user's settings GPO applied on a computer with the remote user's settings

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated in the comments, you can't do this with Group Policy. If this is for a small number of users you can disable printer redirection on the properties of the user account. Simply uncheck the box in the screenshot below.

[image]